# How to make my Cart page uncacheable

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart

I want to make my cart page uncacheable so i have added

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
      <block cacheable="false"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

in /Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml.

So how would i check if it working or i'm doing it right.